# Универсальная архитектура приложения, на примере JDBC и HIbernate

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Допустим у нас есть сервер, с использованием Сервлетов. У нас MySQL. Все общение между сервером и ДБ организованно на JDBC. Но в один момент начальник сказал, что JDBC - это прошлый век и нужно использовать Hibernate, чтобы (допустим) было легче сопровождать проект. Но мы же умные разработчики и знали, что такое может произоти и реализовали универсальную архитектуру(и выбрали подходящий паттерн).
И вот вопрос. Сделал ли я все правильно:

```
//интерфейс для нашего DbServiceImpl, который организовывает методы необходимые для JDBC и Hibernate(к примеру)
public interface DbService<T>{
      void add(T obj);
      T getById(long id);
      T getByObj(T obj); 
      void createTable();
      void dbConditionInfo();
      void open();
      void close(); 
}
// Так же для доступа к данным мы используем DAO, в которому создаются запросы к БД (к примеру для JDBC)
public interface UserDAO<T>{
    void addNew(T obj);
    T getById(long id);
    T getByObj(T obj);
    void dropTable();
    void createTable();
}
// Для JDBC у нас есть Executor класс, который выполняет запросы
// Также еще должен быть интерфейс ResultSetHandler{} для метода resultQuery(но он роли сейчас не сыграет)
public class Executor<T>{
    void updateQuery(String name){}
    T resultQuery(String name){}
}

// И, конечно, есть наш условный транспорт-объект UserDataSet(к примеру)
public class UserDataSet(){
    private long id;
    private String name
    ...
    // Тут дальше Геттеры и Сеттеры

}
```

Правильно я понял, что смогу без проблем сменить JDBC на Hibernate, если захочу.
Просто создам еще один класс, к примеру:

> DbServiceHibernate{}

и новый DAO:

> UserDAOHibernate{}

Сделал я все ли правильно? Возможно, моя архитектура ужасная, если слишком много расписывать, укажите на обшие ошибки. Может я даже не правильно понял, что такое DAO - паттерн.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORM позволяет вам избавиться от кучи шаблонного JDBC-кода, который зачастую на 80% состоит из кода обработки ошибок и лишь на 20% - из полезной логики.

Далее. Задача DAO - скрытие механизма доступа к данным (Data Access Object). Внутри DAO вы и должны скрывать как раз тот факт, где вы храните данные и что используете для их получения - ORM, JDBC или еще что-то. Внутри DAO используйте что угодно.

Данные могут храниться и не в таблицах, поэтому в интерфейсе DAO должны быть только бизнес-методы доступа к вашим объектам и отсутствовать методы вроде open(), close(), dbInfo(), относящиеся к системе хранения. Здесь вы как раз неправильно поняли суть DAO абстракции.
А если вы захотите перейти от JDBC к ORM или наоборот - все, что вам нужно будет сделать - это изменить код DAO.
Надеюсь я смог понятно ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Тогда методы open(), close(), dbInfo() вынести в другой класс? Но они тоже зависят от того, что мы используем. ORM или jdbc

Comment: Не зависят, они зависят только от используемой СУБД. Открывать и закрывать соединения нужно внутри методов DAO. И там уже будет либо JDBC либо ORM.

А если вам нужен метод вроде dbInfo() для получения какой-то служебной информации лучше вынести его в утилитный класс вроде DbUtils.

Comment: Сложно. Мне кажется я слишком много намешал пытаясь упростить архиьектуру. Получается методы open() close(), нужно создавать в классе Dao как приватные, и оперировать ими? Так что бы используещая сторона не знала бы о них? Но тогда, как, к примеру, вызывать dbInfo()?

Comment: да. вы слишком много намешали. Задача DAO - скрыть от клиента работу с БД. Что и как вы там делаете - клиента не волнует.

а что вы получаете в методе dbInfo()?

Comment: К примеру, для Jdbc: DB, version, driver.

Comment: Обычно настройки БД хранят в .properties файлах. А для получения в ходе работы программы какой-то специфической информации о БД лучше создать утилитный класс.

Comment: Сам DAO, я увидел здесь https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/dao и мне не понравилось то, что Connection создаеься прямо в нем( слишком громоздко и тяжело читать). И хотел все лишнюю работу с JDBC или ORM, вынести в DbService(connection, dbinfo, open, close). Что бы в DAO остались лишь бы запросы.

Comment: Ну вот как раз ORM от вас заодно все это и много чего еще и скрывает. Тоже самое делает, например, JdbcTemplate из Spring. Потому что сам JDBC-код читать действительно невозможно.